# Looking for Json-path/(any API) to update any value in given json string in Java

Tags: java, json

Inshort : I am trying to find some api that could just change the value by taking first parameter as jsonString , second parameter as JSONPath and third will be new value of that parameter. But, all I found is this..
https://code.google.com/p/json-path/

This api allows me to find any value in JSON String. But, I am not finding easy way to update the value of any key. For example, Here is a book.json.

```
{
"store":{
    "book":[
        {
            "category":"reference",
            "author":"Nigel Rees",
            "title":"Sayings of the Century",
            "price":8.95
        },
        {
            "category":"fiction",
            "author":"Evelyn Waugh",
            "title":"Sword of Honour",
            "price":12.99,
            "isbn":"0-553-21311-3"
        }
    ],
    "bicycle":{
        "color":"red",
        "price":19.95
    }
   }
 }
```

I can access color of bicycle by doing this.

```
String bicycleColor = JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.bicycle.color");
```

But I am looking for a method in JsonPath or other api some thing like this

```
    JsonPath.changeNodeValue(json, "$.store.bicycle.color", "green");
    String bicycleColor = JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.bicycle.color");
    System.out.println(bicycleColor);  // This should print "green" now.
```

I am excluding these options,

- Create a new JSON String.
- Create a JSON Object to deal with changing value and convert it back to jsonstring

Reason: I have about 500 different requests for different types of service which return different json structure. So, I do not want to manually create new JSON string always. Because, IDs are dynamic in json structure.

Any idea or direction is much appreciated.

**Updating this question with following answer.**

1. Copy [MutableJson.java](https://gist.github.com/vlad-at-yteq/4c42fe4a6874317b81b9#file-mutablejson-java).
2. copy this little snippet and modify as per you need.

   ```
   private static void updateJsonValue() {

   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

   FileReader reader = null;
   try {
       File jsonFile = new File("path to book.json");
       reader = new FileReader(jsonFile);
       jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);

   } catch (Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
   }

   Map<String, Object> userData = null;
   try {
       userData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonObject.toJSONString(), Map.class);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   MutableJson json = new MutableJson(userData);

   System.out.println("Before:\t" + json.map());

   json.update("$.store.book[0].author", "jigish");
   json.update("$.store.book[1].category", "action");

   System.out.println("After:\t" + json.map().toString());

   }
   ```

Use these libraries.

- import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
- import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
- import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

Comment: I think there's a good start with [JSONiq][1], which seems to provide the same update functions as found in [Xquery update][2]. Something like `update value of ... with ...`. [Zorba][3] looks like a good implementation of JSONiq and there's a [Java binding][4]. I have not tried yet, it's just an idea, if it works I'll post an answer.
  [1]: http://www.jsoniq.org/docs/JSONiq-usecases/html-single/index.html#update.example
  [2]: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-replacing-node-value
  [3]: http://www.zorba.io/home
  [4]: http://docs.zorba.io.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.0.0/java/

Comment: To clarify: what you seem to REALLY want to do is have a json template with most of the same values. In other words, you are NOT receiving a JSON string, making one change to it, and forwarding it on somewhere else. Correct?

Comment: @durron597: This is what I am trying to achieve. Read json string --> read any key(i.e. bicycle color) --> update that node(i.e. change color value) --> use modified json string to make requests. Note: I can't have json template as i have different json structure for all server requests. I have to generate json string from java class in order to make a request.  I can always manually create this json string but it is longer route for 500 different json string structures. I am writing automation framework in testng,spring,java without UI to automate stuff where i have to work at json level.

Comment: So your structure is: Client ---json request---> intermediate server (that you're working on now) -----> final server?

Comment: @durron597: Yes. that's absolutely right.

Comment: I am also issuing this problem with the same goal to achieve. This is a little bit strange that community didn't solve this problem yet. It is essential to change values using path. Desired behaviour is that i dont want to write full json path to change a node. I need to use json path, for instance to pass some root elements and write sub json path to change a value in it like it can be done with all implementations of xpath for xml objects.

Comment: @Alexezio : I updated my question with the answer. it is working for me. Let me know, If you still have an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that parsed JSON can be represented in memory as a Map, you can build  an API similar to JsonPath that looks like:

```
void update(Map<String, Object> json, String path, Object newValue);
```

I've quickly done a gist of a dirty implementation for simple specific paths (no support for conditions and wildcards) that can traverse json tree, E.g. $.store.name, $.store.books[0].isbn. Here it is: [MutableJson.java](https://gist.github.com/vlad-at-yteq/4c42fe4a6874317b81b9#file-mutablejson-java). It definitely needs improvement, but can give a good start.

Usage example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MutableJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MutableJson json = new MutableJson(
                new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                    put("store", new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("name", "Some Store");
                        put("books", Arrays.asList(
                                new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                                    put("isbn", "111");
                                }},
                                new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                                    put("isbn", "222");
                                }}
                        ));
                    }});
                }}
        );

        System.out.println("Before:\t" + json.map());

        json.update("$.store.name", "Book Store");
        json.update("$.store.books[0].isbn", "444");
        json.update("$.store.books[1].isbn", "555");

        System.out.println("After:\t" + json.map());
    }

    private final Map<String, Object> json;

    public MutableJson(Map<String, Object> json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> map() {
        return json;
    }

    public void update(String path, Object newValue) {
        updateJson(this.json, Path.parse(path), newValue);
    }

    private void updateJson(Map<String, Object> data, Iterator<Token> path, Object newValue) {
        Token token = path.next();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            if (!token.accept(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())) {
                continue;
            }

            if (path.hasNext()) {
                Object value = token.value(entry.getValue());
                if (value instanceof Map) {
                    updateJson((Map<String, Object>) value, path, newValue);
                }
            } else {
                token.update(entry, newValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Path {
    public static Iterator<Token> parse(String path) {
        if (path.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.<Token>emptyList().iterator();
        }
        if (path.startsWith("$.")) {
            path = path.substring(2);
        }

        List<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String part : path.split("\\.")) {
            if (part.matches("\\w+\\[\\d+\\]")) {
                String fieldName = part.substring(0, part.indexOf('['));
                int index = Integer.parseInt(part.substring(part.indexOf('[')+1, part.indexOf(']')));
                tokens.add(new ArrayToken(fieldName, index));
            } else {
                tokens.add(new FieldToken(part));
            }
        };

        return tokens.iterator();
    }
}

abstract class Token {

    protected final String fieldName;

    Token(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public abstract Object value(Object value);

    public abstract boolean accept(String key, Object value);

    public abstract void update(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry, Object newValue);
}

class FieldToken extends Token {

    FieldToken(String fieldName) {
        super(fieldName);
    }

    @Override
    public Object value(Object value) {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(String key, Object value) {
        return fieldName.equals(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry, Object newValue) {
        entry.setValue(newValue);
    }
}

class ArrayToken extends Token {

    private final int index;

    ArrayToken(String fieldName, int index) {
        super(fieldName);
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public Object value(Object value) {
        return ((List) value).get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(String key, Object value) {
        return fieldName.equals(key) && value instanceof List && ((List) value).size() > index;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry, Object newValue) {
        List list = (List) entry.getValue();
        list.set(index, newValue);
    }
}
```

A JSON string can be easily parsed into a Map using Jackson:

```
Map<String,Object> userData = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{ \"store\": ... }", Map.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for this.

Comment: Updated the code to work with Lists instead of arrays, so that Jackson can be used to parse JSON string into a Map.

Comment: Great. I appreciate your solution. It's done the way i wanted. Thanks a bunch for your help. Just removed previous comments to avoid confusions.

Comment: How to get value from path?

Answer (score 15):

The thing is that the functionality you want is already an undocumented feature of JsonPath. Example using your json structure:

```
String json = "{ \"store\":{ \"book\":[ { \"category\":\"reference\", \"author\":\"Nigel Rees\", \"title\":\"Sayings of the Century\", \"price\":8.95 }, { \"category\":\"fiction\", \"author\":\"Evelyn Waugh\", \"title\":\"Sword of Honour\", \"price\":12.99, \"isbn\":\"0-553-21311-3\" } ], \"bicycle\":{ \"color\":\"red\", \"price\":19.95 } } }";
DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(json).
    set("$.store.bicycle.color", "green").
    set("$.store.book[0].price", 9.5);
String newJson = new Gson().toJson(doc.read("$"));
```

Comment: took me a few hours to spot it as well :) Shouldyou need a JsonObject: `JsonObject jsonObj = new GsonBuilder().create().toJsonTree(dc.json()).getAsJsonObject();`

Answer (score 2):

*Just answering for folks landing on this page in future for reference.*

You could consider using a Java implementation of [jsonpatch](http://jsonpatch.com/). RFC can be found [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)

> JSON Patch is a format for describing changes to a JSON document. It can be used to avoid sending a whole document when only a part has changed. When used in combination with the HTTP PATCH method it allows partial updates for HTTP APIs in a standards compliant way.

You can specify the operation that needs to be performed (replace, add....), json path at which it has to be performed, and the value which should be used.

Again, taking example from the RFC :

```
 [
     { "op": "test", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "foo" },
     { "op": "remove", "path": "/a/b/c" },
     { "op": "add", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": [ "foo", "bar" ] },
     { "op": "replace", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": 42 },
     { "op": "move", "from": "/a/b/c", "path": "/a/b/d" },
     { "op": "copy", "from": "/a/b/d", "path": "/a/b/e" }
   ]
```

For Java implementation, I have not used it myself, but you can give a try to https://github.com/fge/json-patch

Answer (score 0):

So in order to change a value within a JSon string, there are two steps:

1. Parse the JSon
2. Modify the appropriate field

You are trying to optimize step 2, but understand that you are not going to be able to avoid step 1. Looking at the Json-path source code (which, really, is just a wrapper around [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)), note that it does do a full parse of the Json string before being able to spit out the read value. It does this parse every time you call `read()`, e.g. it is not cached.

I think this task is specific enough that you're going to have to write it yourself. Here is what I would do:

1. Create an object that represents the data in the parsed Json string.

   - Make sure this object has, as part of it's fields, the Json `String` pieces that you do not expect to change often.
2. Create a custom Deserializer in the Json framework of your choice that will populate the fields correctly.
3. Create a custom Serializer that uses the cached `String` pieces, plus the data that you expect to change

I think the exact scope of your problem is unusual enough that it is unlikely a library already exists for this. When a program receives a Json `String`, most of the time what it wants is the fully deserialized object - it is unusual that it needs to FORWARD this object on to somewhere else.

Comment: @duron597 :Thanks for the suggestions. I am heading towards writing my own api. Creating objects for my case is still a big decision and it is time consuming as i have to create so many objects for complex JSON structure. But, I will play with native org.json.JsonObject API and other APIs to come up with some simplified solution.

Comment: Personally, I really like Google Gson: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ I would use either that or Jackson, both are far better than the other options.